# Strange event bubbling issue in Titanium Appcelerator alloy project

Tags: ios, ipad, appcelerator, appcelerator-titanium, appcelerator-alloy

I am developing on iOS 9.2 SDK & Titannium SDK v5.1.2.GA.

In my iPad app; there is a product tab page, which has a "Discount" button. When you click it, a Popover with a TextField and Picker is shown like this:

[image]

The above is created on the fly. (not using a controller + view).

This works as intended. I wanted to extend this a little further by recording the given discount to a product in `alloy.js` in a global array variable called `Alloy.Globals.ProductDiscounts = [];` (so it can be used later).

The way I "capture" the new discount price is by listening to the "hide" event on the picker. Then update the global array.

For debugging purpose, I added a console log to make sure it's getting recorded correctly and then in the Appcelerator Studio console window, I started see this endless output like this:

[image]

I had to kill the simulator to stop this weird constant output of nulls.

This is my code so far, any idea why the console window is spazzing out? Also, why isn't my global array isn't getting set? or is it getting set, but I missed the actual console.log entry?

```
// Subscribe to line discount button click event
lineDiscountButton.addEventListener('click', function(e)
{
    // Stop further events
    e.cancelBubble = true;

    // Create popover
    var discountPopover = Titanium.UI.iPad.createPopover({
        arrowDirection: Titanium.UI.iPad.POPOVER_ARROW_DIRECTION_RIGHT,
        orignalPrice: e.source.orignalPrice,
        priceButton: e.source.priceButton
    });
    var discountPopoverView = Titanium.UI.createView({
        width: 250,
        height: 210
    });

    // Create discount popover view wrapper
    var discountPopoverViewWrapper = Titanium.UI.createView({
        top: 10,
        left: 10,
        right: 10,
        bottom: 10,
        layout: 'vertical'
    });
    discountPopoverViewWrapper.add(Titanium.UI.createLabel({
        top: 0,
        left: 0,
        color: '#5C5C5C',
        font: {
            fontSize: 12
        },
        text: 'Enter a new Price'
    }));
    discountPopoverViewWrapper.add(Titanium.UI.createView({
        top: 0,
        height: 1,
        backgroundColor: '#0088CE',
        width: '100%'
    }));
    var discountPrice = Titanium.UI.createTextField({
        top: 0,
        width: '100%',
        height: Titanium.UI.SIZE,
        hintText: discountPopover.orignalPrice,
        value: discountPopover.orignalPrice,
        backgroundColor: '#FFFFFF',
        font: {
            fontSize: 18,
            fontWeight: 'bold'
        },
        color: '#5C5C5C'
    });
    discountPopoverViewWrapper.add(discountPrice);
    discountPopoverViewWrapper.add(Titanium.UI.createLabel({
        top: 10,
        left: 0,
        color: '#5C5C5C',
        font: {
            fontSize: 12
        },
        text: 'Or Select a Discount Percent'
    }));
    discountPopoverViewWrapper.add(Titanium.UI.createView({
        top: 0,
        height: 1,
        backgroundColor: '#0088CE',
        width: '100%'
    }));
    var discountPercentPicker = Titanium.UI.createPicker({
        top: 0,
        width: Titanium.UI.FILL,
        height: 112
    });
    var discountPercentValues = [];
    for (var i = 0; i <= 100; i++) {
        discountPercentValues.push(Titanium.UI.createPickerRow({
            title: i +'%'
        }));
    }
    discountPercentPicker.add(discountPercentValues);
    discountPercentPicker.addEventListener('change', function(e) {
        if (parseInt(e.rowIndex) === 0) {
            discountPrice.value = discountPopover.orignalPrice;
        } else {
            discountPrice.value = (discountPopover.orignalPrice - (discountPopover.orignalPrice * (parseInt(e.rowIndex) / 100))).toFixed(2);
        }
    });
    discountPopoverViewWrapper.add(discountPercentPicker);

    // Add discount popover view wrapper to view
    discountPopoverView.add(discountPopoverViewWrapper);

    // Set popover content view
    discountPopover.contentView = discountPopoverView;

    // Subscribe to popover hide event
    discountPopover.addEventListener('hide', function(e) {
        e.cancelBubble = true;
        Alloy.Globals.ProductDiscounts[discountPopover.priceButton.sku] = parseFloat(discountPrice.value).toFixed(2);
        Alloy.Globals.LiveBasketCollection.executeQuery("UPDATE live_basket SET Price = "+ discountPrice.value +" WHERE Sku = '"+ discountPopover.priceButton.sku +"'");
        discountPopover.priceButton.price = Alloy.Globals.DeviceDefaults.CurrencySymbol + discountPrice.value;
        discountPopover.priceButton.title = (discountPopover.priceButton.basketQuantity > 0 ? discountPopover.priceButton.basketQuantity +' x ' : '') + discountPopover.priceButton.price;
        Titanium.App.fireEvent('redrawBasket');
        discountPopover = discountPopoverView = discountPrice = discountPercentPicker = discountPercentValues = null;
        console.log(Alloy.Globals.ProductDiscounts);
    });

    //  Show popover
    discountPopover.show({
        view: lineDiscountButton,
        animated: true
    });     
});
```

Comment: It's weird that the hide event of the discountPopover gets called over and over again. Something you do in the event listener is triggering the popover to show/hide in a loop. Could it be because you set properties that popover in the callback? Try to remove everything except for the log to see if that is related.

Comment: if I remove `console.log(Alloy.Globals.ProductDiscounts);` and replace it with `console.log(Alloy.Globals.ProductDiscounts[discountPopover.priceButton.sku])` - i do not get the loop and I see just the single value I just set in the array as expected. What a strange thing. Maybe a bug in appcelerator studio?

Comment: That's weird indeed. If you could narrow this down in a as minimal as possible reproducing code, could you please report it as bug? Please check if this is a known issue at the [Appcelerator JIRA](https://jira.appcelerator.org/). If it's not, create a ticket, link to this question but also provide reproducible code, steps and environment information in the ticket itself. Don't forget to drop a link to the ticket here so that others can watch it with you.

Answer (score 0):

Just as a Question... Why are you cancelling bubbling.

without more of the code base I can only try and make a suggestion.

1) addeventlistener.

```
lineDiscountButton.addEventListener('click', setupData);
```

2) setupData

```
Function setupData(e) {

    lineDiscountButton.removeEventListener('click', setupData);

    Your code from the inline function.
}
```

Basically remove the event listener once activated, so add and remove as required.

I don't want to teach you to suck eggs, but to remove an event listener, you have to use exactly the same parameters as adding it. Thus inline function on event listeners are not ideal, although they work separating the code out into its own function is preferable.

Next Alloy globals.... Not good practice. I am guessing you want to have the data only for the duration of the running of the app, and not for future use.

If you need it for future use, you can store the data in properties.

Hope this helps

T.

Comment: `Why are you cancelling bubbling` - why not? The issue I reported looked like events were bubbling up. Why is in-line function on event listeners not ideal? Why are you removing event listener, when the event is fired - what's the purpose behind it? Why are alloy globals not good practice? I am using them because I need the discount data across multiple controllers during the life cycle of the app. I don't need it persisted using properties.

Comment: Sorry been a manic day, ok if I respond tomorrow. Bit of a long answer to rush ..

Comment: Thanks. Appreciate it.